# Python variable loses value when passed to a if statement

Tags: python, sqlite, if-statement, variables, scope

I am trying to retrieve a password hash that i stored in my database. The problem is how i handle when the query is null.

In the case that I search for a **user that exists** the **first print** will print **something** but the in the **second print** that is inside the if statement it will output **None**

I don't understand what is happening. It seems to me that the variable is loosing it's value

```
            db_password = c.execute("SELECT hashed FROM contas WHERE username=?", [username])

            print(db_password.fetchone())

            if(db_password.fetchone() != None):
                print(db_password.fetchone())
                hashed, = db_password.fetchone()

                # Verify if passwords match
                if ((bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf8'), hashed) == False)):
                    print("Wrong credentials")

                else:
                    print("User logged in successfully")


            else:
                print(db_password.fetchone())
                print("User doesn't exist")
```

Comment: What variable are you referring to? `db_password.fetchone()` isn't a variable.

Comment: So the user exists exactly *twice*? Or how come you get into the `if` branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you call `db_password.fetchone()` it fetches the next row of results. But your query only returns one row.

The call in the `if` statement fetches that row. Then the call in the `print()` call tries to fetch the next row, but there isn't another row, so it prints `None`. Then the third call in the variable assignment tries to fetch the next row, but there still isn't another row, so you get an error because you're trying to assign `None` in a tuple assignment.

You should fetch into a variable. Then you can test that and use it in the assignment.

```
row = db_password.fetchone()
if row:
    print(row)
    hashed = row[0]
    ...
else:
    print("user doesn't exist")
```

Comment: "How can i handle the case when db_password.fetchone() fetches nothin?" By using the code shown at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Calling fetchone() will move the cursor to the next row each time and return None if there are no rows available (see documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html)). If you want to just check the one password, store the result of the fetchone call in a variable and use it for future comparisons/printing, i.e.

```
password = db_password.fetchone()
print(password)
if password is not None:
    print(password) # If password is not None, this will print the same thing as the previous print call
    ...
else:
    ...
```